# CakePHP 3.x - change sidebar for a specific controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an application in CakePHP 3.5.13 which features a left hand navigation menu.

In my `Template/Layout/default.ctp` I have this:

```
<body>
    <?= $this->element('left_sidebar', ['lh_menu' => $lh_menu, 'cache' => true]);?>

    <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
</body>
```

This renders `Template/Element/left_sidebar.ctp` on every single page. It also allows me to pass in some data (`$lh_menu`) from my AppController:

```
// src/Controller/AppController.php
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) 
{
    // $lh_menu is some data from a DB used to populate a navigation menu
    $this->set('lh_menu', $lh_menu);
}
```

I have recently added a new Controller (called `SubstanceViewController.php`) and would like to use a different left hand menu (`Template/Element/substance_sidebar.ctp`) for all functions within that controller. I have read about using [View Blocks](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks) but the examples don't show how to use these in relation to controller functions - it is unclear where the code in the documentation would be placed.

Please can someone enlighten me as to how this is done? I will also have a requirement later to pass data in to `substance_sidebar.ctp` via `SubstanceViewController.php` and am not sure if that differs to passing it in via AppController?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to add a `beforeFilter` function in your `SubstanceViewController`, which would `set` a flag which your layout checks for.

In the controller:

```
$this->set('use_substance_sidebar', true);
parent::beforeFilter($event);
```

In the layout:

```
if (isset($use_substance_sidebar) && $use_substance_sidebar) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I managed to use this but have put it in the `initialize()` method in `SubstanceViewController.php` as opposed to the `beforeFilter()` method.

Comment: Either way should work; `beforeFilter` is more symmetrical with the existing code and hence maybe slightly more maintainable in the long run.